# What is the hair bun on a sumo wrestler's head called?

Tags: sports

Sumo wrestlers wear a hair bun on the top of their heads and I want to know what it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called 大銀杏 *ōichō*, which is a type of 髷 *mage* (bun/topknot).